# no system table found in data database

Tags: sql-server, database, windows-authentication, windows-nt

I have an Accounting package that uses a SQL Server database.

To connect to this database I have two options:

1. Windows NT authentication
2. SQL Server authentication

When I use option 2 (SQL Server authentication) with `SA` user account, the application takes a long time to startup and connect.

When I use option 1 on a workstation the application boots up normally but when I try to connect to the database I get an error NO System table found in database.
If I go directly to the server and use the same option (Option 1), it connects with no problem.

Comment: Well, SQL is not a Database, it is a query language... But I have no clue on your problem.

Comment: You will have to provide more information. How does the application connect? On the server, do you use the application to connect, or another tool? What exactly is the error message you get? Unrelated, but why would you use sa credentials from an application? That's just asking for trouble.